# Ошибки на ровном месте

Tags: android

Вчера запускал проект,всё работало.

Сегодня решил добавить анимированные переходы между активити,уже ошибки выбивает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибки:

```
Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process H:\AndroidFinall\app\build\intermediates\transforms\instantRunSlicer\debug\7
Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing com/example/com/shcherbuk/MyService$AsynchronousGet$1.class
Error:com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: class name (com/example/com/shcherbuk/MyService$asynchronousGet$1) does not match path (com/example/com/shcherbuk/MyService$AsynchronousGet$1.class)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process H:\AndroidFinall\app\build\intermediates\transforms\instantRunSlicer\debug\7
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.com.shcherbuk"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.2'
    compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:20.50.533.12'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

**Update:**
Сделал CleanProject,теперь ошибка такая:

```
Error:Could not read path 'H:\AndroidFinall\app\build\intermediates\transforms\instantRunSlicer\debug\7\com\example\com\shcherbuk'.
> H:\AndroidFinall\app\build\intermediates\transforms\instantRunSlicer\debug\7\com\example\com\shcherbuk
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перезапустил Android Studio и всё заработало.
Ох уж этот Android)